# How to add and/or modify a point in XY data set in abaqus viewer using python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a data set, obtained form the .odb file by script. I would like to change coordinates of the first point ((0, 26.7852) to (0,0)) in this data set in the same script. From .rpy file I found how to do this for the entire set (see below), but don't have idea for a single point. Please help

```
xQuantity = visualization.QuantityType(type=DISPLACEMENT)
yQuantity = visualization.QuantityType(type=FORCE)
session.xyDataObjects['F_vs_U'].setValues(data=((0, 26.7852), (0.3, 26.7852), (
    0.394435, 35.446), (0.490063, 44.1067), (0.581765, 52.7674), (0.675743, 
    61.4282), (0.770288, 70.0889), (0.865283, 78.7497), (0.949015, 87.4104), (
    1.03486, 96.0711), (1.12699, 104.732), (1.21825, 113.393), (1.30867, 
    122.053), (1.38952, 130.714), (1.45982, 139.375), (1.52214, 148.036), (
    1.59321, 156.696), (1.66979, 165.357), (1.75083, 174.018), (1.83359, 
    182.679), (1.90974, 191.339), (1.96586, 200), ), 
    sourceDescription='Data modified in editor', axis1QuantityType=xQuantity, 
    axis2QuantityType=yQuantity, )
```

Comment: i suspect you need to extract the whole array, modify the value, and reset the whole thing.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you wish to accomplish? Do you just want to generate a list with F and U for plotting? Also if the first point should be (0,0) maybe you should define a boundary condition to impose that.

Comment: Actually, I found another approach. This array is a combination from two steps. In the first one I apply small displacement on a rigid body to establish contact between that and a deformable body. Then, in the second step, I apply certain load on the rigid body in the same direction. Previously I got CFvsU graph for both steps. Since there were no CF in the 1 step, abaqus extrapolated the first CF value to the zero displacement. Instead of this, I created RFvsU on the first step, CFvsU on the second one and then used the command append(A,B).

Comment: You should post that as a an answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found another approach. This array is a combination from two steps. In the first one I apply small displacement on a rigid body to establish contact between that and a deformable body. Then, in the second step, I apply certain load on the rigid body in the same direction. Previously I got CFvsU graph for both steps. Since there were no CF in the 1 step, abaqus extrapolated the first CF value to the zero displacement. Instead of this, I created RFvsU on the first step, CFvsU on the second one and then used the command append(A,B).